# debugging LDAP library / connection Wireshark / or whatever

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap, wireshark

Unfortunately I don't have access to Ldap server.

I just need to answer question why I can't connect Ldap server using python library `ldap`.

In wireshark I already some transmision:

- Syn
- Syn/Ack
- Ack

But then unfortunatelly:

- Rst, Ack

Unfortunately library is not showing any logs either password is wrong or I spotted some connections issues.

So I want to ask if there is something more what I can do beside of debugging **ldap** library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable logging in the library.

```
import ldap;

# enable python-ldap logging
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 4095)

# enable openLDAP logging
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://yourserver:port', trace_level=2)
```

Taken from: http://lpetr.org/blog/archives/how-to-enable-logging-in-python-ldap